# Position image and text on one vertical line

Tags: html, css, image

I want to place an image beside a text like this:

```
<div class="views">text<img src="..."></img></div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

but it should look like:

[image]

any idea how to position the elements on one vertical line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- Experiment with different `vertical-align` CSS values, like `baseline`, `middle`, etc.
- Set the `line-height` CSS property of `#views` to the same height as your image.

Comment: hm this doesn't work for me, maybe I should wrap the text with a span element

Comment: it works now, I wrapped it with a span and applied vertical-align: text-bottom; to the img element